# Add a "delete" link for the alt OpenID to Area 51

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, area-51, openid

It is possible to remove the alternate OpenID on most Stack Exchange sites. However, there is no option to do so in Area 51, and this capability should be added.

Comment: you mean you want to get in withOut loging in ... as a  guest?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done. You can now delete your alternate OpenID on Area 51.